# Find, Replace and Count multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Old values

```
1. A + B + C
2. A + B
3. A + D + E +I
```

Condition

> (A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4, E=5, I=6)

New values

```
1. 6
2. 3
3. 16
```

> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(K2,INDEX(OLD,O5:O9),INDEX(NEW,P5:P9)),INDEX(OLD,O5:O9),INDEX(NEW,P5:P9))
>
> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(K2,INDEX(OLD,O5:O9),INDEX(NEW,P5:P9)),INDEX(OLD,O5:O9),INDEX(NEW,P5:P9))

So, actually I want to change and count values .Only sum numbers without letters, symbols using excel formula

[image]

Comment: It’s quite hard to understand what your problem is. Can you tried and rephrase and actually ask a question?

Comment: 1. I need to change letters to nunbers . 2. Сomlete math sum

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your workbook so I can see an exact example?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvG50.png

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to throw a UDF into your project then this will do it for you.

```
Public Function CalculateBasedOnAlphabetIndex(ByVal strFormulaToEvaluate As String) As Double
    Application.Volatile

    Dim i As Long, strLetter, dblNumber As Double, varValue As Variant

    strFormulaToEvaluate = UCase(strFormulaToEvaluate)

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 65 To 90
        strLetter = Chr(i)

        Err.Clear

        varValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strLetter, Range("AlphaLookup"), 2, False)

        If Err.Description = "" Then
            dblNumber = varValue
        Else
            dblNumber = i - 65 + 1
        End If

        strFormulaToEvaluate = Replace(strFormulaToEvaluate, Chr(i), dblNumber, , , vbTextCompare)
    Next

    On Error GoTo 0

    CalculateBasedOnAlphabetIndex = Evaluate(strFormulaToEvaluate)
End Function
```

... there's no error checking as such but it will work as long as you stick to the basics of formula writing.

To make the above work, you need to create a named range over the top of the conversion table, that range needs to be called "**AlphaLookup**" and is used in a **VLOOKUP** in the code to get the letters corresponding value ...

[image: AlphaLookup]

... that will then be used to lookup the letter and find it's assigned value.  There's a neat trick to this table though.  You only need to maintain letters in that table IF the letters corresponding number is not the same as its index in the alphabet.

E.g. you said A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5 and I = 6, so when filling that range, all you would have to enter in, based on the above, would be **I** because I's position in the alphabet is not 6th, it's 9th.

If you're not familiar with how to get to the Visual Basic Editor, press **Alt + F11** and it will open up for you.

From here, insert a new **Module** and then paste that code in.

You can now apply a formula in a cell directly, like thus ...

```
=CalculateBasedOnAlphabetIndex(A1)
```

This UDF will also evaluate formulas with numbers as well, so the following examples will work.

[image]

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Are there any options with calculation based not on alphabetical way ?  If random letter costs for instance 20

Comment: @JohnBordevskiy meaning you want to control the value of the letter rather than the value being derived from its index in the alphabet? Oh I see, you had I = 6. Yes, it can be done. Are those values hard coded? I.e do they need to change?

Comment: I guess I need to keep it simple

Comment: That's why I need to use the matrix from condition and change by applying values from transition matrix. I shared my examples in the very beginning that can not work. Based on this one, could you please help me to changes

Comment: @JohnBordevskiy yep, that’s pretty easy, I’ll get back to you. It was just an oversight on my behalf.

Comment: Right'o, check my answer now.

Comment: Hey Im not familiar with Visual basic. Could I perform this operation using comand line in excel only ?

Comment: COuld be possible using tthis example https://exceljet.net/formula/find-and-replace-multiple-values

Comment: @JohnBordevskiy the big problem with that is that the formula will be as long as your arm. For every single letter, you need to perform a vlookup and substitute. It’d be out of control. If you follow my simple instructions, you’ll get your result. Open the VBA editor using Alt + F11, insert a new module and paste the code I gave you, here’s a video showing you how.  https://youtu.be/IIuKCxPlaTY

Comment: The other problem you face is, changing the textual values using a formula only gets you part of the way.  You still need to evaluate that string as a formula and you have to do that in VBA.  You really just need to implement what I've given you, it's going to do the job.  :-)